# PDF.JS highlight words

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I need to highlight some words on my PDF using PDF.JS ( https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js).

Some people say

```
PDFFindBar.findField.value = keywords;
PDFFindBar.dispatchEvent('')
```

But I cannot access to *PDFFindBar.findField.value*

How I can do it ?

Reference:
"https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/4448"

Answer (score 1):

It only highlights the text temporarily but if that's what you want here is what you need to do to get it working!

`PDFViewerApplication.findBar.findField.value = 'General';
PDFViewerApplication.findBar.dispatchEvent('');`